# Red-Black Gauss-Siedel for Sparse Matrices

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Using Red-Black method, we arrange the solution matrix as a 2D array of (n*n) elements, and alternatively perform R & B computations.

In the case of sparse matrices, should we also consider the zero entries or just the non-zero entries alone as we do for Jacobi or normal Siedel?

Sorry if the question was too basic. I am new to iterative solvers.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

(1) You have not represented the Sparse matrix in a different representation i.e. You are not using the Array or Linked List representation of Sparse Matrices. In this case, you will definitely need to consider all entries as without accessing a particular entry you will not know whether an entry is 0 or not.

(2) You have represented the Sparse Matrix in a shorter form using arrays or Linked Lists. In this case it's easier to see to if an entry is 0 or not as only non-zero entries are stored. Hence in this case you may not consider entries which are zero.